# Big O notation complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider an operation like binary multiplication between one array with size (1*4) and matrix with size (4*8), as you know we obtain as the output an array of size (1*8).

Is the complexity of this operation O(1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sizes of the matrices are specified in your question.

Since the size of the problem never changes the complexity will be O(1).

The complexity would be O(n) when you would need to treat your input data exactly once.

For example, multiplying every number in an array of length n by 2 is of complexity O(n).

Now as far as your problem is concerned, if the size of your matrices was variable then the run time would be O(n^3), if we assume a naive implementation.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Mr. OlivierLi. When we say it is O(n) ?

Comment: I think the complexity is O(7) because we have 4 multiplication operations and 3 addition operations.

Comment: @Sam. I wrote it like that because that is the convention when comparing orders. It's like writing O(7*1). The 7 is ignored because it's a constant. Same would go for O(7*n) which would usually be written O(n).

Comment: "`O(7)` if and only if `O(1)`."

Comment: @Sam if it's clear tell me, which is greater: O(21) or O(22)?

Comment: @SK9: Suppose A = 1*(0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0) + 0*(1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1) + 1 * (1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0) + 0 * (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0). In this case, we have 4 multiplication operations (each operation multiplies one bit by eight bits). Then we have three summation operations. The total number of operations is seven. As you now, the microprocessor now a days can do the multiplication during one operation using the registers. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @sk9 : • When the program takes the same time to run and no matter how big the input is. In this case the complexity is constant (i.e., O(1)). For example , Making tea for yourself every morning is O(1). Also, the most cooking procedures are O(1), that is, it takes a constant amount of time even if there are more people to cook. Whereas, Reading a book is probably O (log n) in terms of time versus interest. So, We can say O(7) is the constant time complexity      and written as O(1) time.